# Onde posso baixar a biblioteca hump?

Tags: lua

Na minha conta do Stack Overflow americana,eu perguntei como eu podia fazer o jogo esperar um determinado número de segundos.Um dos resultados foi usando o hump.timer,como por exemplo:

```
function love.load()
    timer=require "hump.timer"
    face=love.graphics.newImage("face.png")
end

function love.update(dt)
    timer.update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    timer.after(1,function()
        love.graphics.draw(face)
    end)
end
```

mas então ocorreu um erro dizendo que o modulo "hump.timer" não foi encontrado

Então eu perguntei por que isso aconteceu para a pessoa que me passou o hump.timer,e ele disse:Voce baixou a biblioteca hump e adicionou ela na pasta do seu projeto?E também,"hump.timer" na linha do require quer dizer que o timer.lua está dentro de uma pasta hump.Então certifique-se que é ai que timer.lua está localizado.
Senão voce pode pôr o arquivo timer.lua no mesmo diretório de main.lua,e apenas usar require "timer"

Só que eu não sei onde baixar essa biblioteca.Se alguem me ajudar,ficarei agradecido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/vrld/hump

Na moral, bastou uma pesquisa Google por hump library lua.

Comment: brigado. E que eu tava pesquisando timer.lua download kkk

Comment: Se resolveu o seu problema aceite a resposta pra no futuro as pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida saberem que o link é correto.

Comment: obrigado por me lembrar,eu esqueci desse detalhe